# React count array in API and reset / start again

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, math, state

Hi Everyone I have been trying to create a Rota in React that uses a API of staff members below is the code I have been using. At the moment this reads the array and then adds a random number to the state every 3s.

What I want it to do is count from 0 to the value of the array and then reset. Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { once, every, daily } from 'bella-scheduler';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          data: [0]
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3333/staff')
      .then((response) => {
          this.successShow(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          this.successShow('error');
      });
  }


  successShow(response) {
        console.log(response.data);

        every('3s', () => {

            var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*(response.data.length))
            this.setState({person: response.data[i].name});
            console.log('Resolved task.');

        });

    }


  render() {
      return (
          <div className="main">
            <h2 className="title">Rota</h2>
            <h3>{this.state.person}</h3>
          </div>
      );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a counter instead of the random() indexer to show the names after each other.

So add a cnt or counter variable to your state then increase the number every 3s but use it with % like below to prevent indexing problem.

for the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          data: [0],
          cnt:0
      }
  }
```

and for the successShow function:

```
successShow(response) {
        console.log(response.data);

        every('3s', () => {

            var i = this.state.cnt++;
            this.setState({person: response.data[i%response.data.lenght].name});
            console.log('Resolved task.');

        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have added this in but I was getting the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

I changed "var i = this,state.cnt++;" to "var i = response.data.length.cnt++;" but then get a error of Cannot create property 'cnt' on number '5' 

The reason for this is that the object does have 5 values but it counts from 0 - 4 not 1 - 5

Comment: every thing is current, but you have to initialize the first value for the parameter cnt in the constructor. I added the constructor changes to.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I have it working now just in your comments above length has a typo. 

Do you have any links to support this method? so I know where to look next time?

Comment: these are algorithm skills, you have to understand % for above example. look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp